# The time complexity for a 1-NN (nearest neighbor) search using a KD tree (i.e. balanced binary tree) is in what range?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

The time complexity for 1-NN search using a KD tree (i.e. balanced binary tree) is in what range?
Assume there are N points in the dataset

There's a hint here, but still can't figure it out: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/ml-clustering-and-retrieval/complexity-of-nn-search-with-kd-trees-BkZTg

A) O(N2) - O(N3)

B) O(log N) - O(N)

C) O(N logN) - O(N2)

D) None of the above

Answer (score 0):

TLDR. The best and average case for finding the nearest neighbor with a kd-tree is going to be O(log₂(N)). But the worst case can be closer to O(N).  Hence the answer is `B) O(log N) - O(N)`

Assuming the kd-tree is already built, each level of the tree normally bifurcates the entire range of points across one of the given dimensions.  Just like a binary tree.  So if the tree is perfectly balanced and each leaf node consists of just one point, there will be approximately N leaves across at the bottom of a tree that is log₂(N) levels high.  Hence, to find the original point in the tree is always log₂(N).

But you aren't looking for the original point, you're looking for it's closest neighbor. So that's where it gets complicated.  In practice, your leaf nodes don't contain just one point. They contain some reasonable number of points (~ log₂(N) or some small number like "10") that are considered to be in the same box or "cluster".

So when you find the initial point, you can immediately do a distance computation on the other points in the leaf node cluster to find an initial candidate for nearest neighbor. Hence, the highest probability is that the nearest neighbor is in the same cluster with a lesser probability its in one of the adjacent leaf node clusters.  As you recurse up the tree, you have to decide if recursing the other child node is needed based on the dimension and mid-point value of each node. But if you've already found the nearest neighbor, you probably won't do too many more recursions down the tree.

But it's theoretically possible, that the initial bifurcation of the set of points split the original point with it closest neighbor. And in some crazy layout of points, you wind up having to do a distance computation with most of the points in the tree.  Hence, O(N).  Try making a 2-d graph of points and creating this scenario yourself.